# XSL Transformation and XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am developing an application were I need to transform XML documents that look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE words SYSTEM "words.dtd">
<words>
<word id="word_1">Alfa</word>
<word id="word_2">Beta</word>
<word id="word_3">Gamma</word>
<word id="word_4">Delta</word>
<word id="word_5">Zeta</word>
</words>
```

Using a XSLT stylesheet. I would like the result of the transformation to be (in this case) `Delta` and this is the XSL I am using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="Hurrengo_Hitza">word_4</xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="word/[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]">
  <html>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It shows no result, what do I have to change in the XSLT? Something wrong in the XPath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param in XSLT needs to be preceded by a dolar sign ($)

So try:

```
<xsl:template match="word[@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza]">
```

**UPDATE:**

I think you are only allowed `variables` on the match attribute on XSLT 2.

But here is how you could do it:

```
<xsl:param name="Hurrengo_Hitza" select="'word_4'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//word[@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza]">
          <html>
          <body>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
            </tr>
          </body>
          </html>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it seems to be a problem with having a variable on the match attribute. I'm getting XPath error : Undefined variable

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer, it should be word[@id] rather than word/[@id]

Answer (score 3):

**There are two problems here**:

1. `word/[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]` is syntactically invalid XPath -- a predicate showld follow a node-test within a location step.
2. `<xsl:template match="word/[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]">` . Even if corrected to `<xsl:template match="word[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]">` which is now syntactically valid XPath expression and match pattern, this template doesn't match any node -- it matches any `word` the string value of whose `id` attribute is equal to the string valu of one of its `Hurrengo_Hitza` elements. However no `word` element in the provided XML document has a child element named `Hurrengo_Hitza` -- therefore the template doesn't match any node and will not be executed at all.

**Solution**:

What you want is a match pattern like: `word[@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza]` -- a variable or parameter reference must start with the `$` character.

**If you change**:

```
<xsl:template match="word/[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]">
```

**to**:

```
<xsl:template match="word[@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza]">
```

you'll have a working *XSLT **2.0*** solution.

**However, in XSLT 1.0 (which you seem to be using), it is illegal** to have a variable or parameter reference within a match pattern.

An XSLT solution, therefore will be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="word">
  <xsl:if test="@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza">
   <!-- Processing here -->
  </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="word/[@id = Hurrengo_Hitza]">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="word/[@id = $Hurrengo_Hitza]">
```

Comment: As stated below I already corrected that mistake but still no result. Ideas?